# Clarify purpose of fields in Thrift TSSLSocket

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm trying to understand the semantics of the SSL Sockets in Thrift. In particular what the fields: ca_certs, keyfile,and certfile accomplish.

Is the usage that on a client the `keyfile` is a path to a private key and then this is verified using a cert on the server side using a cert in the `certfile`

The fields seem inverted to me, in that I would expect to see a keyfile field on the server side and not client side.

Is the certfile on the server side truly a pem (meaning a combination of public cert and private key) or is it just a cert?

what is the proper usage to authenticate client to server and vice versa?

```
TSSLSocket Initializer

def __init__(self,
           host='localhost',
           port=9090,
           validate=True,
           ca_certs=None,
           keyfile=None,
           certfile=None,
           unix_socket=None,
           ciphers=None):
"""Create SSL TSocket

@param validate: Set to False to disable SSL certificate validation
@type validate: bool
@param ca_certs: Filename to the Certificate Authority pem file, possibly a
file downloaded from: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem  This is passed to
the ssl_wrap function as the 'ca_certs' parameter.
@type ca_certs: str
@param keyfile: The private key
@type keyfile: str
@param certfile: The cert file
@type certfile: str
@param ciphers: The cipher suites to allow. This is passed to
                the ssl_wrap function as the 'ciphers' parameter.
@type ciphers: str

Raises an IOError exception if validate is True and the ca_certs file is
None, not present or unreadable.
"""
```

Server side:

```
class TSSLServerSocket(TSocket.TServerSocket):
SSL_VERSION = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1

def __init__(self,
           host=None,
           port=9090,
           certfile='cert.pem',
           unix_socket=None,
           ciphers=None):
```

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Yes. This has changed in recent versions, but the following has worked for me. certfile should simply be the signed cert, keyfile should be the private key and ca_certs should be the entire chain that leads to the root ca and which signed the certfile. This is our current setup in production.